# C++ Macro to use enum to access a type?

Tags: c++, filter, enums, macros, preprocessor

I'm unsure how to word this. I have an enum that basically has values that represent other enum types. This is for a sorting algorithm I'm working on (think like filters on a shopping page).

So I have say

```
enum Sorting { COLOR, PRICE };

enum Color { RED, BLUE };
```

is there a way to make a Macro where I input COLOR and return the type Color?

```
#define ENUM_ASSOCIATION(A, B)
#define ENUM_TYPE(A) //returns B from ENUM_ASSOCIATION

enum Sorting{ COLOR, PRICE };
ENUM_ASSOCIATION(COLOR, Color);

enum Color { RED, BLUE };

void someFunc()
{
    DoSomething<ENUM_TYPE(COLOR)>();
}
```

I'm new to C++ Preprocessors and trying to get a handle on them. I feel like this shouldn't be too difficult to accomplish, but I'm unsure how to go about it, if it's possible at all

***EDIT:***

So this is what I'm using. I have had no compile errors, though I haven't yet been able to test it. Any enum declared with these macros will use the Assoc struct, which may or may not cause issues. If it does, possibly just add an AliasName parameter to each macro and replace Assoc with that.

```
// Allow use of ENUM_ASSOCIATION to create type aliases
#define DECLARE_ENUM_ASSOCIATION(T) template<T> struct Assoc;

// Creates a type alias, allowing to call ENUM_TYPE() and get the type V
// Remember to use only after both T and V have been declared previously
#define ENUM_ASSOCIATION(T, V) \
template<> \
struct Assoc<T> \
{\
    using type = V;\
};

#define ENUM_TYPE(T) Assoc<T>::type;
```

Comment: Why can't you just type the name `Color` to get the type `Color`? Why do you need a different name for it?

Comment: This was an oversimplified example, most of my enum values have abbreviations before them (SO_COLOR, SO_PRICE, etc.) which I have to use as a standard my team wants to keep. And sometimes I want to create an enum value with a different name than the type

Comment: @DemonBismuth Imho there are only 2 reasons to prefer enums over enum classes: 1. They are implicitly convertible to the underlying type and 2. You can use them in both C and C++. The drawback of enums is that every enum constant is just a constant of the underlying type and can pollute the namespace. The very reason for adding a prefix to the constant name is to avoid name conflicts. For this reason I strongly recommend not violating these naming conventions for existing enums. If you introduce a new enum that's not used from C code, go with enum class instead and not add any prefix.

Comment: Btw: using an enum class you don't even need to use a macro for the purpose you describe: `enum class Color {Red, Blue}; ... using EnumType = decltype(Color::Red);`

Comment: @fabian is what I'm trying to achieve at least possible? sure this might be easier to name them the same (and I'll get on making them enum classes), but I also want to learn more about preprocessors. If this doesn't exist, I'll stop, but this kind of Macro could be useful in many different cases. I'm working in Unreal Engine and the amount of workarounds I have to do just to make anything readable by the engine is frustrating, something like this could help in more ways than just this.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of association in C++ is usually done with *meta-functions*. E.g.

```
template <Sorting> struct Assoc;
template <> Assoc<COLOR> struct Assoc {using type = Color};

DoSomething<Assoc<COLOR>::type>();
```

Of course, you can also `#define ENUM_ASSOCIATION(COLOR, Color)` to wrap

```
  template <> Assoc<COLOR> struct Assoc {using type = Color};
```

and `#define ENUM_TYPE(COLOR)` to wrap

```
Assoc<COLOR>::type
```

Comment: Does this work with enum classes (I'm switching for this one at the recommendation of others)? putting ENUM_ASSOCIATION(Sorting::RED, Color) says "Sorting::RED is not a type name."

Comment: You should have `ENUM_ASSOCIATION(Sorting::COLOR, Color)`, not `Sorting::RED`

Comment: oops I mistyped. this example was an oversimplified version of the enum, in my file I typed it correctly (ie how you did). I'm still getting that error however

Comment: I think it should work with enum class. I cannot tell why it is not working without seeing the actual source.

Comment: `#define ENUM_HAS_ASSOCIATION(T) template<typename T> struct Assoc;
#define ENUM_ASSOCIATION(T, V) template<> Assoc<T> struct Assoc {using type = V;};
#define ENUM_TYPE(T) Assoc<T>::type;` + `ENUM_HAS_ASSOCIATION(eOmnibusOrder)
ENUM_ASSOCIATION(eOmnibusOrder::RARITY, eRarity)` (sorry i don't know if theres a better way to format or reply I havent used this site much)

Comment: That will not work - neither with `enum` nor with `enum class`. You tried to generalize it for arbitrary enum type, but did not do it right. Let me try ...

Comment: Okay, it possibly was the order in which I had placed those macros (i forgot to put them after both eOmnibusOrder and eRarity were declared). that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: I still don't understand why your macros work - they seem wrong. But I give up and will not spend any more time on this.

Comment: no you are correct, I did not use macros, I just hand wrote the structs. Now it looks like the macros will not work with this. But even without macros your original answer is what I was looking for, so I'll take it from there at least.

Answer (score 2):

This is text book application for meta-functions. Since the question is tagged C++, I'd avoid macro solutions and go with common practice.

Let's check the solution first:

```
enum Sorting { COLOR, PRICE };
enum Color { RED, BLUE };
enum Price { CHEAP, EXPENSIVE };

// auto is used for non type template parameters
template <auto any_enum_value>
struct SortCategory;

template <>
struct SortCategory<COLOR>
{
    using type = Color;
};

template <>
struct SortCategory<PRICE>
{
    using type = Price;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1dbbc3084737768)

The code above provides a meta function called `SortCategory`; this is a struct that can be specialized for values of the `Sorting` enumeration. You can basically do anything this way, above the following mappings are chosen:

```
SortCategory<COLOR> -> Color
SortCategory<PRICE> -> Price
```

the mapped type (enumeration) is the nested type alias as shown in the demo.

EDIT: The `SortCategory` has been updated to accommodate any non type template argument. Using `auto` you can pass values of any enumeration which makes your mapping scale out of the sorting enum type.

Comment: My only issue is I'm working in Unreal and it hates templates (as do I, seeing them as completely inferior to c# generics). I've never seen "using" used that way before. I think I may still use a macro to streamline creating these nested type aliases. Is there a way to make "template<Sorting sort_type>" even more generic, so that it could potentially be applicable to other enums?

Comment: @DemonBismuth C# generics are rather similar to Java generics and rely on type erasure, which has a cost at runtime. Templates is purely compile-time, you  can do type erasure with templates and much more

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I still prefer the flexibility in being able to inherit generic types, even with that cost. The cost is worth the usability

Comment: @DemonBismuth Big chunk of the Core API in Unreal engine is templated. Even have an early implementation of concepts and "requires" clauses. I don't know where you're getting that Unreal engine "hates" templates, it uses C++ so that's that. If you hate templates because of the "unease" of use that's a different story. If you prefer C# generics I'd suggest Unity that does leverage that stuff. C++ (especially in game dev space) is all about not paying the extra cost

Comment: Unreal has not been kind to me, I prefer Unity but my job is using Unreal. Doing things so that they interface well with blueprints (so our artists can use them) makes using templates difficult, and the documentation for how to make custom, compatible templated code is non-existent or difficult to parse.

Comment: @DemonBismuth There is a learning curve, it's steep but I believe it pays off. That said I respect that you refrain from features you haven't mastered yet, it shows responsibility in coding. Templates are powerful but can be a hazard when used improperly (and I've seen this a lot). FYI I updated the answer with what you asked (generalization to any enum type)